# Prevent CPU Time Exceeded Governor limit

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, governorlimits, bulk-api, cpulimit

I have a very small flow. It simply calls an apex action, then an update records element. This is set to run on create or update on the account object. Here's a picture:

[image]

Although this flow is pretty simple, I am facing a problem; I am consistently getting a CPU Time Exceeded error when bulk uploading new accounts. I understand the bulkification process pretty good, that salesforce takes all my bulk records and splits them into groups of 200 records for processing (that is, all the governor limits apply to the groups rather than the entire upload). So, I am a bit puzzled why I am receiving the CPU limit with such a small flow. I do expect the issue lies within the apex action I am calling, but still a bit puzzled, because the apex is not grossly inefficient, and I have written my invocable methods to allow for the bulkification process. Here's the code:

```
public class CompareOrganizationNames {
    
    public class ComparisonParams {
        @InvocableVariable
        public String orgName;
        
        // Default constructor
        public ComparisonParams() {
        }

        // Constructor with orgName parameter
        public ComparisonParams(String orgName) {
            this.orgName = orgName;
        }
    }
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='Compare Organization Names' description='Compares two organization names, regardless of casing, punctuation, and organization suffix (ex. WAL-MART, INC. and walmart would result in a match.')
    public static List<String> compareOrgNames(List<ComparisonParams> requests) {
        System.debug('Starting!');
        List<String> results = new List<String>();
        
        //Regex pattern for punctuation
        String punctuationRegex = '[\\p{Punct}\\s]+|(?i)(llc|corp|inc|co|edu)$';
            
            for (ComparisonParams request : requests) {
                String org = cleanOrgName(request.orgName, punctuationRegex);
                results.add(org);
            }
            System.debug('Returning!');
            return results;
        }
    
    private static String cleanOrgName(String organizationName, String punctuationRegex) {
        return organizationName.trim().toLowerCase().replaceAll(punctuationRegex, '');
    }
}
```

Just as a brief summary of this code, I am expecting 1 - 200 account records (200 in the case of bulk upload) that all have an org name property. I am wanting to 'Clean' the org name so that I have something to compare to in other automations (which are irrelevant to this problem). The idea is to set the cleaned org name to all lower case, remove any spaces, remove any punctuation, and remove any common trailing company suffix (ex. llc, edu, etc...). Also of note is that this flow runs completely fine if I were to create or update a single records. It also completes with a limited number batch size (50 to 100 records complete no problem). It fails when I attempt to upload a large number of records and the flow runs on a transaction size of 200 records.

After some testing, it seems that this apex is getting through about 150 records pretty consistently before erroring out (so pretty close). However, this is puzzling to me, because it doesn't seem overly inefficient. I know it is bad to put a loop in a loop, or if I were to retrieve all the accounts within the apex itself it would have to process a lot more records because it wouldn't operate in the bulkification process, but since I only have a single loop and it is guaranteed that the max number of records coming through the invocable method is only 200, I am confused why it is failing, or even anywhere close, to the cpu governor limit of 10 seconds.

Is there any way to add some sort of record limit that enters a flow (ideally only allow 100 records at a time, instead of 200 - and for context, this subflow will eventually be invoked as a subflow, rather than from the data upload tool)? Or, do I possibly need to add some sort of bulkification process to the apex itself?

Any thoughts on how to make my code more efficient would be very appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: A small correction: The splitting of records into 200-record chunks does not give you a fresh set of governor limits for each chunk. Governor limits are cumulative through the entire transaction, and generally 1 debug log == 1 transaction. So if you're working on 1000 records, and each chunk of 200 consumes 25 SOQL queries, you would run into the # of SOQL queries limit on the 5th chunk (records 801-1000).

Comment: That said, how many records are you working on when you're encountering this issue? Are you using the Bulk API directly, or through something like the Salesforce-provided dataloader? What is your batch size (i.e. are you limiting it to batches of 150-200? or is your batch size set to something like 1000?)

Comment: Also, do you have any other triggers/flows that run when you do the update action? Because those would also contribute to limit usage here. Have you been able to capture a debug log where you overrun the limit (which should give you more details about when/where the limit is being overrun)?

Comment: Please correct me if I am mistaken, but I believe that in the context of a salesforce flow, the bulkification process creates a new transaction for every batch. Please see this documentation and let me know what you think: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5   and also a helpful answer from sfdcfox: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/401351/help-understanding-salesforce-governor-limits-in-a-flow-while-using-the-data-imp

Comment: My understanding is that this works when a flow is triggered from large imports, such as another create records flow or the data import tools. In the context of a non-invocable apex class, every batch would be contained in the same transaction, like you said.

Comment: My given context is through the data loader, AND also the flow is called from a button click (custom button on a list view). I am not accessing the bulk api directly, however my research has led me to believe that when a flow is triggered by any sort of bulk insert, every batch of 200 creates a new transaction for a fresh set of governor limits. The only exception is if a flow is triggered from a non-invocable apex class.

Comment: And no, I do have a couple other flows that are running on similar triggers, but I have deactivated them for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't the code, it's the flow. An After Save Flow causes all triggers to run a second time when updating the current records. This nearly doubles the CPU time you're using. It sounds like your trigger logic takes at least 37ms per record, so when you double that, it's closer to 75ms minimum. I'd write a unit test too verify. At any rate, changing the flow to a Before Save Flow will reduce the CPU usage by about 50%, and as such, you'll be allowed to build update with impunity.

Comment: That explanation makes sense; however, since I am calling an apex action, the flow has to be an after save flow. I am not aware of a way to create a before save flow that contains an apex action. How might I accomplish this?

Comment: @LukeSharon Oh yeah, I'd forgotten about that restriction. Still, maybe a pure trigger would be a better idea for this use case?

Comment: yeah, your answer got me thinking about that. I ended up adding a before-insert before-update apex trigger and it did the trick. One thing I am curious about though. Why does the idea of an after-insert flow with an update element cause ONLY a single re-trigger? The expected behavior would be an infinite loop, but it does appear to only be running one more time. Does this have something to do with the transaction context?

Comment: @LukeSharon Yes, recursive updates don't fire the entire process over again. This is noted in [triggers and order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).